# update pandas.DataFrame within a group after .groupby()

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
                                                          time
offset   ts                      op                           
0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318 BuildIndex            282.604
                                 Compress              253.649
                                 Decompress              2.953
                                 Deserialize             0.063
                                 InsertIndex             1.343
4.960683 2015-10-27 18:36:37.959 BuildIndex            312.249
                                 Compress              280.747
                                 Decompress              2.844
                                 Deserialize             0.110
                                 InsertIndex             0.907
```

Now I need to update the dataframe (in-place is OK): for each group, subtract the time for `op == 'Compress'` from the one for `op == 'BuildIndex'` - *within the same group*.

What is the most elegant way to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [xs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) (cross-section) to do this:

```
In [11]: df1.xs("Compress", level="op")
Out[11]:
                                     time
offset   ts
0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318  253.649
4.960683 2015-10-27 18:36:37.959  280.747

In [12]: df1.xs("BuildIndex", level="op")
Out[12]:
                                     time
offset   ts
0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318  282.604
4.960683 2015-10-27 18:36:37.959  312.249

In [13]: df1.xs("BuildIndex", level="op") - df1.xs("Compress", level="op")
Out[13]:
                                    time
offset   ts
0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318  28.955
4.960683 2015-10-27 18:36:37.959  31.502
```

The subtraction works on the index labels (in this case offset and ts), so no need to group.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! `.xs()` solves the problem. Here's how I use it:

```
diff = df.xs("BuildIndex", level="op") - df.xs("Compress", level="op")
diff['op'] = 'BuildIndex'
diff = diff.reset_index().groupby(['offset', 'ts', 'op']).agg(lambda x: x)
df.update(diff)
```

The code looks quite ugly, though. Can someone suggest more elegant solution?

Comment: You should accept my answer and ask this as another http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235. That said I think unstack that level first, no need for groupby etc.

Comment: Just did that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620485/elegant-groupby-and-update-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

Most elegant solution found! Just three lines of code:

```
df = df.unstack("op")
df['time', 'BuildIndex'] -= df['time', 'Compress']
df = df.stack()
```

(Here's the [Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620485/elegant-groupby-and-update-in-pandas))