# elegant groupby and update in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `pandas.DataFrame` object:

```
       offset                      ts               op    time
0    0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318       Decompress   2.953
1    0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318  DeserializeBond   0.015
32   0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318         Compress  17.135
33   0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318       BuildIndex  19.494
34   0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318      InsertIndex   0.625
35   0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318         Compress  16.970
36   0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318       BuildIndex  18.954
37   0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318      InsertIndex   0.047
38   0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318         Compress  16.017
39   0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318       BuildIndex  17.814
40   0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318      InsertIndex   0.047
77   4.960683 2015-10-27 18:36:37.959       Decompress   2.844
78   4.960683 2015-10-27 18:36:37.959  DeserializeBond   0.000
108  4.960683 2015-10-27 18:36:37.959         Compress  17.758
109  4.960683 2015-10-27 18:36:37.959       BuildIndex  19.742
110  4.960683 2015-10-27 18:36:37.959      InsertIndex   0.110
111  4.960683 2015-10-27 18:36:37.959         Compress  16.267
112  4.960683 2015-10-27 18:36:37.959       BuildIndex  18.111
113  4.960683 2015-10-27 18:36:37.959      InsertIndex   0.062
```

I want to group by `(offset, ts, op)` fields, and sum up the `time` values:

```
df = df.groupby(['offset', 'ts', 'op']).sum()
```

So far so good:

```
                                                    time
offset   ts                      op                     
0.000000 2015-10-27 18:31:40.318 BuildIndex       56.262
                                 Compress         50.122
                                 Decompress        2.953
                                 DeserializeBond   0.015
                                 InsertIndex       0.719
4.960683 2015-10-27 18:36:37.959 BuildIndex       37.853
                                 Compress         34.025
                                 Decompress        2.844
                                 DeserializeBond   0.000
                                 InsertIndex       0.172
```

The problem is, I have to subtract `Compress` time from `BuildIndex` - *within each group*. [I was recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557239) to use `DataFrame.xs()`, and I came up with the following:

```
diff = df.xs("BuildIndex", level="op") - df.xs("Compress", level="op")
diff['op'] = 'BuildIndex'
diff = diff.reset_index().groupby(['offset', 'ts', 'op']).agg(lambda val: val)
df.update(diff)
```

It does the job, but I have a strong feeling that there must be a more elegant solution to the problem.

Can someone suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Your line:

```
diff = diff.reset_index().groupby(['offset', 'ts', 'op']).agg(lambda val: val)
```

Is unnecessary as diff is unchanged (since it's already unique via the previous groupby).

---

A little hack is to use `drop_levels=False` along with .values (so the index is ignored when subtracting), this is a little cheeky as it assumes that every group has both a "BuildIndex" and a "op" row, which may be unsafe.

```
In [11]: diff = df1.xs("BuildIndex", level="op", drop_level=False) - df1.xs("Compress", level="op").values

In [12]: diff
Out[12]:
                                     time
offset     ts           op
2015-10-27 18:31:40.318 BuildIndex  6.140
           18:36:37.959 BuildIndex  3.828
```

---

I would be tempted to unstack here, as the data is really two dimensional:

```
In [21]: res = df1.unstack("op")

In [22]: res
Out[22]:
                              time
op                      BuildIndex Compress Decompress DeserializeBond InsertIndex
offset     ts
2015-10-27 18:31:40.318     56.262   50.122      2.953           0.015       0.719
           18:36:37.959     37.853   34.025      2.844           0.000       0.172
```

It's unclear if there's value in this being a MultiIndex column though:

```
In [23]: res.columns = res.columns.get_level_values(1)

In [24]: res
Out[24]:
op                       BuildIndex  Compress  Decompress  DeserializeBond  InsertIndex
offset     ts
2015-10-27 18:31:40.318      56.262    50.122       2.953            0.015        0.719
           18:36:37.959      37.853    34.025       2.844            0.000        0.172
```

Then the subtraction is much easier:

```
In [25]: res["BuildIndex"] - res["Compress"]
Out[25]:
offset      ts
2015-10-27  18:31:40.318    6.140
            18:36:37.959    3.828
dtype: float64

In [26]: res["BuildIndex"] = res["BuildIndex"] - res["Compress"]
```

*I suspect that's the most elegant...*

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot for your help. It turned out, you can address multilevel columns as tuples, and after unstacking, simply write: `df['time', 'BuildIndex'] -= df['time', 'Compress']`. Now I am happy :-)